# How to add same product with different specifications in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of products and a shopping cart. Let's say I have a product something like this:

```
   {
     "ProductId" : "1",
     "ProductName" : "Knee Caps",
     "Specifications" : {
           "Size" : ["S","M","L","XL","XXL"],
           "GrossWeight" : "200gm each",
           "Colour" : ["Beige","Grey"]
          },
     "SellingPrice" : 80
}
```

What I did so far is this:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("productTable") != null)
{
  productTable = JSON.parse(localStorage["productTable"]);
  productTable[Id]={ProductId : Id, Colour : selectedColour, Size : selectedSize, QuantityAdded : selectedQuantity};
 }
 else {
   productTable[Id]={ProductId : Id, Colour : selectedColour, Size : selectedSize, QuantityAdded : selectedQuantity};                    
 }
```

What this code is doing is, it add's the product on the first time but if i want the same product with different **Sizes** and **Color's**, it replaces the original one. Now I know this approach is not completely correct. Can someone please help me to figure out how can i add same product with different specifications?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you wanted to keep `Specifications` property if it exists. I hope this will work. Feel free to let me know in case you get some error. Hopefully, you can get the clue aboout what I am doing

```
if(localStorage.getItem("productTable") != null)
{
  productTable = JSON.parse(localStorage["productTable"]);
  productTable[Id]={
      ProductId : Id,
      Colour : selectedColour, 
      Size : selectedSize,
      Specifications : checkSpecification(productTable[Id].Specifications,size,weight,color)
      QuantityAdded : selectedQuantity
  };
}
 else {
   productTable[Id]={ProductId : Id, Colour : selectedColour, Size : selectedSize, QuantityAdded : selectedQuantity};                    
}

function checkSpecification(obj,size,weight,color){
  if(obj){
     obj['Size'].push(size);
     obj['GrossWeight'] = weight || '';
     obj['Colour'].push(color);

     return obj;
  } 
}
```

Comment: hi @Shashank, thankyou for reply, but it's not working as i expected. It's replacing the existing product in my cart.

Comment: Would you mind creating a demo on https://plnkr.co/edit/. I'll fix over it

Comment: After thinking, I guess i need to change my product table design, What if i add an internal id to my product table? Will it work?

Comment: @Aditya : I am afraid I cant help you much unless I see the code and what you are trying to achieve. but I do feel that you are not doing it properly with this logic.